# Вопрос о защите данных от взлома на андроид

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Мне интересно через root можно взломать следующие вещи?
1. Публичные переменные.
2. Приватные переменные.
3. Переменные сохраненные в PlayerPrefs.
4. Сериализованные переменные.
5. И тут не обязательно рут: Если я создал событие DateTime, которое произойдет в определенное время (например:завтра в 21:00), то просто поменяв дате на телефоне он может обнулить таймер?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Публичные переменные.
>
> Приватные переменные.
>
> Переменные сохраненные в PlayerPrefs.
>
> Сериализованные переменные.

Это все ломается при желании.

Смирись -- все что сохраняется на компьютере/телефоне клиента под контролем самого клиента.

В случае компьютера -- через ArtMoney. В случае андроида -- какими-то аналогами.

> 5.И тут не обязательно рут: Если я создал событие DateTime, которое произойдет в определенное время (например:завтра в 21:00), то просто поменяв дате на телефоне он может обнулить таймер?

Никто тебя не заставляет проверять время исключительно по локальному времени девайса. Ты можешь требовать подключение к интернету и проверять время через него.

Или перенести логику с клиента к себе на сервер и проверяй на сервере не было ли подмены чего-либо. Даты, времени, количества жизней и т.д. -- всего что угодно. И если данные были подменены - возвращай на клиент сообщение что нужно подправить назад на правильные значения.

---

UPD: Как еще вариант - хранить некую переменную которая проверяет чек-сумму PlayerPrefs. Если чек-сумма изменилась без твоего ведома, то стереть нафиг настройки все :) От ArtMoney не спасет, зато спасет от изменения данных вручную и в реализации достаточно просто и быстро должно быть.

Comment: Как всегда выручаешь, примерно понимал, хотел подтверждения опасениям.

Comment: @PinPin Данные можно обфусцировать. Например жизни игрока: самое простое - умножать на определенную константу или по более сложной формуле, можно еще контрольную сумму добавить для проверки. Это значительно усложнит извлечение и подмену данных.

Comment: Обфускация помогает от дебага приложения, но никак не от подмены значения в оперативной памяти. А именно этот подход используется в ArtMoney и его аналогах.

Comment: Я имел в виду обфускацию хранящихся данных, а не кода. Т.е. например имеем в виду данные "3", а после обфускации в памяти запишется например "-42", а когда читаем эту переменную для использования - она передается как "3" и т.д.

Comment: Я думаю что человек который сможет залезть в playerPrefs игры на андроиде *(что сможет далеко не каждый из пользователей андроида)* сможет и запустить аналог ArtMoney. :) Не уверен в целесообразности применения этого подхода. Но он имеет право на существование, все же. Как минимум знать что так тоже можно -- это тоже полезно.

Comment: Использовать собственные CryptString алгоритмы на сохраняемые данные, усложнит задачу стороннему читателю :)

Comment: Вся проблема упирается в один вопрос: а зачем кому-то вообще защищать данные в игре? Если это соло игра без доната - да пусть пользователь хоть обломается - он сам себе игру испортит. Если вопрос в донате - синхронизация через сервер валюты/времени. Если это вообще онлайн игра, то там эта синхронизация с сервером происходит на постоянной основе.